# Count fuel liters with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

We have created a fuel sensor in our lab with Arduino in order to get fuel data from vehicles. Regarding the code below, I receive an error

> PARSE ERROR: 'attachInterrupt': this function needs to be defined.

Could you please advice?

```
int pin = 2;
volatile unsigned int pulse;
float volume = 0;
float flow_rate =0;
const int pulses_per_litre = 2000;
int count_pulse;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(0, count_pulse, RISING);

}

void loop()
{
    pulse=0;
    interrupts();
    delay(1000); 
    noInterrupts();

    Serial.print("Pulses per second: ");
    Serial.println(pulse);

    flow_rate = pulse * 1000/pulses_per_litre; //

    Serial.print("FUEL FLOW rate: ");
    Serial.print(flow_rate);
    Serial.println(" milliliters per second");

    volume = volume + flow_rate * 0.1; //Time Interval is 0.1 second

    Serial.print("Volume: ");
    Serial.print(volume);
    Serial.println(" milliliters");
}

void count_pulse()
{
pulse++;}
```

Comment: You have a int count_pulse and a function count_pulse, that confuses the compiler.

Comment: and add forward declaration line `void count_pulse();` before `setup()`

Comment: @Juraj Doesn't the Arduino IDE do that for you?

Comment: there is some problem for function as parameter

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `count_pulse` as a variable and NOT as function prototype.

```
int pin = 2;
volatile unsigned int pulse;
float volume = 0;
float flow_rate =0;
const int pulses_per_litre = 2000;

void count_pulse(); \\ <--- Function prototype

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(0, count_pulse, RISING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize `pulse` to zero in its definition at line 2.

The message "'pulse': used without being explicitly initialized" is due to the count_pulse() function: The compiler can't analyze the run-time behavior of the code, nor your intentions. Some interrupts could arrive before loop() runs, so in fact, `pulse` could very well get incremented without having been initialized. You may not care about and can discard the first few readings, but the compiler doesn't (and shouldn't!) guess that.